# Random output when computing power

Tags: c++

Here is code of my program that is not working. This program should calculate the result of the first number raised to second number. Where's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "iveskite betkoki skaiciu" << std::endl;
    // "enter number:"
    int v1;
    std::cin >> v1;
    std::cout << "iveskite skaiciu kiek kartu jus norit pakelti pirmaji skaiciu" << std::endl;
    // "Enter the number of times you want to raise the first number"
    int v2;
    std::cin >> v2;
    int rez;
    // result
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt != v2; ++cnt)
        rez *= v1;  //  rez = rez * v1;
    std::cout << v1
              << " pakeltas "
              << v2 << " kartu ,yra: /t"
              << rez << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please try to explain what exactly happens when a program is "not working". That way it's much easier for people to help you when your mistake is less obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not initializing `rez`, and thus the behavior is undefined.

You should have `int rez = 1;` and treat the case where `v1 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `rez`; C++ doesn't do that for you, `rez` will most probably still contain some random number, therefore your program will most likely output a random number (but actually it's undefined behavior); you should initialize it to 1, e.g.

```
int rez = 1;
```

Or, in your simple case you could initialize it with `v1`'s value:

```
int rez = v1;
```